# When to add 's' to a verb

Tags: verbs

As per my knowledge of English, we append 's' to a verb when we are talking about facts and the subject is he/she/it and . for example, "He plays tennis every day". But today I was reading a newspaper and I came across a sentence

**Salman Khan announces 'Loveratri' title changed to 'Loveyatri'**.

Why 's' is appended in the above sentence? and should not it be like

**Salman Khan announced 'Loveratri' title changed to 'Loveyatri'**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **Present** tenses of a verb  (**Present Indefinite** Tense in your first sentence; also Present Perfect '*ha**s** changed*' and Present Perfect Continuous '*ha**s** been changing*') used with a **singular 3rd-person** subject (Salman Khan here) take **-s/-es** endings. You have **Past** Indefinite in the second sentence, so there's no such an ending.

As for the tense used for 'talking about a fact'. Different tense versions are possible (including Present Perfect, 'has announced', if it's about a singular recent event). The Present simple one used here can mean e. g. that the process of announcement still takes place here and there.